# Error encountered when trying to save config.inc.php

Tags: php

so when I try to go to `LAMPP` > `PHPMyAdmin` > `config.inc.php`, and change my port as I am getting an issue on my PHPMyAdmin,

> Error MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings.

So for this I need to change password, or auth_type from `config` to `cookie`, however, whenever I do that and click save (CMD + S), it shows this error:

[image: Error Image]

Any clue on what's occurring? Also, I am on Mac. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like the file permissions on the config folder can't be written to by PHP myadmin.  You may need to check that the web-server user that is running PHP can write to the appropriate files, by adding it to a group, or you may need to use the `chmod` command to set the permissions to 644 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

open your mac terminal

**type:**

```
cd /Users/aayuvreddy/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/phpmyadmin
```

*press enter*

**type:**

```
sudo chmod 7777 config.inc.php
```

*press enter
type your system password then again press enter
now save that file again it will be done*

Comment: When I typesudo chmod 7777 config.inc.php, it says: chmod: Unable to change file mode on config.inc.php: Operation not permitted

Comment: Hey I got it. I'm in the file.

Comment: It still displays that error message though:

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: This is due to you do not have administrator rights.. so for administrator right you need to switch user to the super user on same location please type `sudo su` press enter and then type your password, Now you are login from super user so be careful.  Now type again `chmod 7777 config.inc.php` press enter then it will be change... also please close your terminal after doing this

Comment: tell me have you edited controluser in config.inc.php???

Comment: What should I do in control user. I commented out controluser and controlpass, and one of the "Connection failed" error messages are gone.